# Net movement of the center of a circle based on radial movement.

Tags: geometry

I am working on a basic setup to measure the positional movement of a test tube within a rack using two lasers. One will measure movement in the $x-\text{direction},$ the other in the $y-\text{direction}.$ The reference points for the laser will be what we set as $(0,0)$ on a cartesian plane.

However, if there is any change in the position, the laser will read a different length. In the picture below, I have the "lasers" positioned at $x=3$ and $y=3.$

My question is:

> How will I determine the net displacement of the center of the circle, based on the distance from the two lasers?

*In this figure, I obviously know the net movement, but in a less hypothetical setting.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the intersection between a line and a circumference?

Comment: What is it that you are measuring? The arc that face the laser?

Comment: @Moti , Yes, the laser is measuring the distance from the arc.

Comment: If each measure includes direction and distance convert it into (x,y) and than if you know the radius of the circles solve the two equations of distance from the center to resolve the (x,y) of the center.